# Confidence interval for exponential curve fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, confidence-interval

I'm trying to obtain a confidence interval on an exponential fit to some `x,y` data (available [here](http://pastebin.com/TDFLgtvi)). Here's the MWE I have to find the best exponential fit to the data:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Read data.
x, y = np.loadtxt('exponential_data.dat', unpack=True)

def func(x, a, b, c):
    '''Exponential 3-param function.'''
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c

# Find best fit.
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
print popt

# Plot data and best fit curve.
scatter(x, y)
x = linspace(11, 23, 100)
plot(x, func(x, *popt), c='r')
show()
```

which produces:

[image]

How can I obtain the 95% (or some other value) confidence interval on this fit preferably using either pure `python`, `numpy` or `scipy` (which are the packages I already have installed)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63560689/10375049

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gabriel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26042460/1628638) is incorrect.  Here in red the 95% confidence band for his data as calculated by GraphPad Prism:
[image: Prism confidence and prediction bands]

Background: the "confidence interval of a fitted curve" is typically called **confidence band**.  For a 95% confidence band, one can be 95% confident that it contains the true curve.  (This is different from **prediction bands**, shown above in gray.  Prediction bands are about future data points.  For more details, see, e.g., this [page](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/curve-fitting/index.htm?reg_graphing_confidence_and_predic.htm) of the GraphPad Curve Fitting Guide.)

In Python, [kmpfit](https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfit.html) can calculate the confidence band for non-linear least squares.  Here for Gabriel's example:

```
from pylab import *
from kapteyn import kmpfit

x, y = np.loadtxt('_exp_fit.txt', unpack=True)

def model(p, x):
  a, b, c = p
  return a*np.exp(b*x)+c

f = kmpfit.simplefit(model, [.1, .1, .1], x, y)
print f.params

# confidence band
a, b, c = f.params
dfdp = [np.exp(b*x), a*x*np.exp(b*x), 1]
yhat, upper, lower = f.confidence_band(x, dfdp, 0.95, model)

scatter(x, y, marker='.', s=10, color='#0000ba')
ix = np.argsort(x)
for i, l in enumerate((upper, lower, yhat)):
  plot(x[ix], l[ix], c='g' if i == 2 else 'r', lw=2)
show()
```

The `dfdp` are the partial derivatives ∂f/∂p of the model f = a*e^(b*x) + c with respect to each parameter p (i.e., a, b, and c).  For background, see the [kmpfit Tutorial](https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html#confidence-and-prediction-intervals) or this [page](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/curve-fitting/index.htm?reg_how_confidence_and_prediction_.htm) of the GraphPad Curve Fitting Guide.  (Unlike my sample code, the kmpfit Tutorial does not use [`confidence_band()`](https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfit.html#kmpfit.Fitter.confidence_band) from the library but its own, slightly different, implementation.)

Finally, the Python plot matches the Prism one:

[image: kmpfit confidence bands]

Comment: Great answer Ulrich, thank you very much! Indeed, I believe my old answer actually obtains the *prediction bands* rather than the fitted curve's *confidence interval*. You seem to know your way around these stats, could you confirm this is the case?

Comment: I just added prediction bands to the Prism plot.  So your old answer does not calculate prediction bands.  This [page](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/curve-fitting/index.htm?reg_how_confidence_and_prediction_.htm) of the GraphPad Curve Fitting Guide states how they are calculated in Prism.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [uncertainties](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/) module to do the uncertainty calculations.
`uncertainties` keeps track of uncertainties and correlation. You can create correlated `uncertainties.ufloat` directly from the output of `curve_fit`.

To be able to do those calculation on non-builtin operations such as `exp` you need to use the functions from `uncertainties.unumpy`.

You should also avoid your `from pylab import *` import. This even overwrites python built-ins such as `sum`.

A complete example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import uncertainties as unc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import uncertainties.unumpy as unp


def func(x, a, b, c):
    '''Exponential 3-param function.'''
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c

x, y = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

a, b, c = unc.correlated_values(popt, pcov)

# Plot data and best fit curve.
plt.scatter(x, y, s=3, linewidth=0, alpha=0.3)

px = np.linspace(11, 23, 100)
# use unumpy.exp
py = a * unp.exp(b * px) + c

nom = unp.nominal_values(py)
std = unp.std_devs(py)

# plot the nominal value
plt.plot(px, nom, c='r')

# And the 2sigma uncertaintie lines
plt.plot(px, nom - 2 * std, c='c')
plt.plot(px, nom + 2 * std, c='c')
plt.savefig('fit.png', dpi=300)
```

And the result:
[image: result]

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `uncertainties` package, I'll give it a try it looks very interesting. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh man, I did not even know that I was looking for it all the years.

Answer (score 5):

**Notice**: the actual answer to obtaining the fitted curve's confidence interval is given by Ulrich [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37080916/1391441).

---

After some research (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72047/when-fitting-a-curve-how-do-i-calculate-the-95-confidence-interval-for-my-fitt), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92131/how-to-calculate-95-confidence-interval-for-non-linear-equation?rq=1) and [1.96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96)) I came up with my own solution.

It accepts an arbitrary X% confidence interval and plots upper and lower curves.

[image]

Here's the MWE:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import stats


def func(x, a, b, c):
    '''Exponential 3-param function.'''
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c


# Read data.
x, y = np.loadtxt('exponential_data.dat', unpack=True)

# Define confidence interval.
ci = 0.95
# Convert to percentile point of the normal distribution.
# See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score
pp = (1. + ci) / 2.
# Convert to number of standard deviations.
nstd = stats.norm.ppf(pp)
print nstd

# Find best fit.
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
# Standard deviation errors on the parameters.
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
# Add nstd standard deviations to parameters to obtain the upper confidence
# interval.
popt_up = popt + nstd * perr
popt_dw = popt - nstd * perr

# Plot data and best fit curve.
scatter(x, y)
x = linspace(11, 23, 100)
plot(x, func(x, *popt), c='g', lw=2.)
plot(x, func(x, *popt_up), c='r', lw=2.)
plot(x, func(x, *popt_dw), c='r', lw=2.)
text(12, 0.5, '{}% confidence interval'.format(ci * 100.))    

show()
```

Comment: when you already have x,y from `exponential_data.dat` why do you again say `x = linspace(11,23,100)`. It would be better to call it `X1` or something so that people dont get confused. I can understand that it is for the confidence lines.

Comment: I also found out another solution. The covariance matrix `pcov` in our curve_fit has the 1sigma error which can be used as well. Check this [WEBSITE](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/media.usm.maine.edu/~pauln/ScipyScriptRepo/CurveFitting.ipynb)

Comment: @ThePredator because if I'd called the full `x` instead of `linspace(11,23,100)` the function would try to plot the fitted curve to touch all those `x` values. Try it for yourself commenting  out `x = linspace(11, 23, 100)` and see what happens :)

Comment: @ThePredator The covariance matrix `pcov` is exactly what my answer uses: `perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`. Those are the 1 sigma errors, that's how you obtain them (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html))

Comment: I don't think that this solution is correct. I see two major problems here: (1) Choosing the margin of one parameters confidence interval gets you to 95%, taking the also the second gets you to 1-0.05**2 --> 99.75%. So your confidence interval here is way bigger. (2) You assume your parameters to be independent, what is an legit *approximation* only when your co-variances are small.

Answer (score 4):

[`curve_fit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) returns the covariance matrix - pcov --  which holds the estimated uncertainties (1 sigma).   This assumes errors are normally distributed, which is sometimes questionable.

You might also consider using the [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) package (pure python, built on top of scipy), which provides a wrapper around scipy.optimize fitting routines (including leastsq(), which is what curve_fit() uses) and can, among other things, calculate confidence intervals explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a fan of simple bootstrapping to get confidence intervals. If you have `n` data points, then use the `random` package to select `n` points from your data WITH RESAMPLING (i.e. allow your program to get the same point multiple times if that's what it wants to do - very important). Once you've done that, plot the resampled points and get the best fit. Do this 10,000 times, getting a new fit line each time. Then your 95% confidence interval is the pair of lines that enclose 95% of the best fit lines you made.

It's a pretty easy method to program in Python, but it's a bit unclear how this would work out from a statistical point of view. Some more information on why you want to do this would probably lead to more appropriate answers for your task.