# Timeseries plots to show percentiles and other statistics of the population

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Consider the examples for [`tsplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html#seaborn.tsplot) (time-series plot) in [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/), e.g. the one shown below.

Do pandas, matplotlib or seaborn include similar functionality to plot translucent bands representing percentiles or standard deviations of **a population** provided in a dataframe?

Reading the documentation, it looks like `sns.tsplot` plots confidence intervals for the sampling distribution of the estimator via bootstrapping, which is of course different.

[image]

Comment: I need to do this too!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164114/show-confidence-limits-and-prediction-limits-in-scatter-plot) help ?

Answer (score 2):

Worth mentioning that the proposal by raphael conflates percentiles and confidence intervals, which are very different statistics. For example, if you use `ci=[0,100]` in `tsplot`, you will **not** get bands showing the minimum and maximum of your data.  An issue requesting inclusion of percentiles was raised on the [Seaborn github page](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/842) in January 2016, with a clear--and curt--reply that this was not currently possible.

A potential work-around has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767719/timeseries-plot-with-min-max-shading-using-seaborn).

Answer (score -1):

From the [seaborn `tsplot` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html#seaborn.tsplot), it seems you can provide multiple percentile confidence bands. The example below plots the 68th percentile and 95th percentile confidence bands (`ci=[68, 95]`). You can also change the value of the line to, for example, the median with `estimator=np.median` or `np.mean`.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(22)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 31)
data = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(10, 31) + np.random.randn(10, 1)
ax = sns.tsplot(data=data, ci=[68, 95], color="m")
```

[image]