# Timeseries plot with min/max shading using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to create a 3-line time series plot based on the following data [image: Long Dataframe], in a Week x Overload graph, where each Cluster is a different line.

I have multiple observations for each (Cluster, Week) pair (5 for each atm, will have 1000). I would like the points on the line to be the average Overload value for that specific (Cluster, Week) pair, and the band be the min/max values of it.

Currently using the following bit of code to plot it, but I'm not getting any lines, as I don't know what unit to specify using the current dataframe:

```
    ax14 = sns.tsplot(data = long_total_cluster_capacity_overload_df, value = "Overload", time = "Week", condition = "Cluster")
```

[GIST Data](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/03d6eec77b9b5e03feb995e4276b61b6)

I have a feeling I still need to re-shape my dataframe, but I have no idea how. Looking for a final results that looks like this [image]

Comment: Best I could come up with so far is using sns.pointplot and getting this: https://gyazo.com/425b31b23f9d5009c12502f3113361ef

Comment: honestly, is that plot not exactly what you're looking for? would you like the inter-line shading to be less and the edge lines to be darker?

Comment: That looks similar to what I'm looking for, but if I expand it, they're actual confidence intervals (vertical lines for each point), so not a continuous timeseries so to speak. And yes, I would like the inter-line shading to be less.

Comment: could you create a gist with a sufficiently large sample of the data and add it to the question?

Comment: I think I have added it, I hope that's what you were referring to? And thank you for your patience, I'm really new to this.

What I'm looking for is for example the first point on the line plotted for Cluster 1 to be the average Overload for (Cluster 1, Week 1) observations, while the shaded area upper and lower limit be the Max and Min value for the same observations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based off [this incredible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293687/standard-deviation-and-errors-bars-in-seaborn-tsplot-function-in-python), I was able to create a monkey patch to beautifully do what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns    
import seaborn.timeseries

def _plot_range_band(*args, central_data=None, ci=None, data=None, **kwargs):
    upper = data.max(axis=0)
    lower = data.min(axis=0)
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    ci = np.asarray((lower, upper))
    kwargs.update({"central_data": central_data, "ci": ci, "data": data})
    seaborn.timeseries._plot_ci_band(*args, **kwargs)

seaborn.timeseries._plot_range_band = _plot_range_band

cluster_overload = pd.read_csv("TSplot.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
cluster_overload['Unit'] = cluster_overload.groupby(['Cluster','Week']).cumcount()

ax = sns.tsplot(time='Week',value="Overload", condition="Cluster", unit="Unit", data=cluster_overload,
               err_style="range_band", n_boot=0)
```

Output Graph:
[image]

Notice that the shaded regions line up with the true maximum and minimums in the line graph!

If you figure out why the `unit` variable is required, please let me know.

---

If you do not want them all on the same graph then:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.timeseries


def _plot_range_band(*args, central_data=None, ci=None, data=None, **kwargs):
    upper = data.max(axis=0)
    lower = data.min(axis=0)
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    ci = np.asarray((lower, upper))
    kwargs.update({"central_data": central_data, "ci": ci, "data": data})
    seaborn.timeseries._plot_ci_band(*args, **kwargs)

seaborn.timeseries._plot_range_band = _plot_range_band

cluster_overload = pd.read_csv("TSplot.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
cluster_overload['subindex'] = cluster_overload.groupby(['Cluster','Week']).cumcount()

def customPlot(*args,**kwargs):
    df = kwargs.pop('data')
    pivoted = df.pivot(index='subindex', columns='Week', values='Overload')
    ax = sns.tsplot(pivoted.values, err_style="range_band", n_boot=0, color=kwargs['color'])

g = sns.FacetGrid(cluster_overload, row="Cluster", sharey=False, hue='Cluster', aspect=3)
g = g.map_dataframe(customPlot, 'Week', 'Overload','subindex')
```

Which produces the following, (you can obviously play with the aspect ratio if you think the proportions are off)
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this works perfectly! Regarding the unit, I'll be creating many more similar plots for my current project, and if I do figure out why "unit" is compulsory, I'll get back to you.

Comment: I think the second plot is much better. Great job.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I hope others find this useful too.

Comment: This answer is out of date with seaborn version 0.10.1. I tried using `seaborn.tsplot()` and I got `AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'tsplot'`

Answer (score 5):

I finally used the good old `plot` with a design (subplots) that seems (to me) more readable.

```
df = pd.read_csv('TSplot.csv', sep='\t', index_col=0)
# Compute the min, mean and max (could also be other values)
grouped = df.groupby(["Cluster", "Week"]).agg({'Overload': ['min', 'mean', 'max']}).unstack("Cluster")

# Plot with sublot since it is more readable
axes = grouped.loc[:,('Overload', 'mean')].plot(subplots=True)

# Getting the color palette used
palette = sns.color_palette()

# Initializing an index to get each cluster and each color
index = 0
for ax in axes:
    ax.fill_between(grouped.index, grouped.loc[:,('Overload', 'mean', index + 1)], 
                    grouped.loc[:,('Overload', 'max', index + 1 )], alpha=.2, color=palette[index])
    ax.fill_between(grouped.index, 
                    grouped.loc[:,('Overload', 'min', index + 1)] , grouped.loc[:,('Overload', 'mean', index + 1)], alpha=.2, color=palette[index])
    index +=1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I'll make a similar one to this as well, and consult with my supervisor see which one we agree on.

Quick question regarding this: for some reason, when using the DF stored in memory, it won't run. getting KeyError: ('Overload', 'mean', 1). However, if I save it to csv, then re-import it using the index_col = 0 parameter, it works. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm sure your supervisor will be on my side ;-). Tell me ! 
No idea for the `DataFrame` stored in memory since I cannot reproduce the problem. It is not related to the index as the example can run without `index_col = 0`. I think you should check (print) the `DataFrame` stored in memory.

Comment: I have, multiple times, both using print statements and in PyCharm. I'm definitely missing out on something, but I can barely make sense of PyCharm's output https://gyazo.com/1a362bd8f2031f9bb88bed386888e7b6 (DF is read from CSV, DF1 is the one stored from memory). It's very weird though, as if I save it, and load it again (using delim = ',' and col_index=0 as params), it works... 
I'll get back to you tomorrow evening to let you know which graph my supervisor thought was better! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @SilviuTofan I updated my answer to also include code to plot in this format as well.

Comment: @RomainX. Follow-up: met with my supervisor today, he liked both, but will be using neither. When running it for a large number of iterations, the value will tend to be equal to each other. While helping us understand the current situation, I will still have to figure out new ways of calculating and visualising my objectives.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's interesting. If you need help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I **really** thought I would be able to do it with `seaborn.tsplot`. But it does not quite look right. Here is the result I get with seaborn:

```
cluster_overload = pd.read_csv("TSplot.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
cluster_overload['Unit'] = cluster_overload.groupby(['Cluster','Week']).cumcount()
ax = sns.tsplot(time='Week',value="Overload", condition="Cluster", ci=100, unit="Unit", data=cluster_overload)
```

Outputs:

[image]

I am really confused as to why the `unit` parameter is necessary since my understanding is that all the data is aggregated based on `(time, condition)` The [Seaborn Documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html) defines `unit` as

> Field in the data DataFrame identifying the sampling unit (e.g.
>   subject, neuron, etc.). The error representation will collapse over
>   units at each time/condition observation. This has no role when data
>   is an array.

I am not certain of the meaning of 'collapsed over'- especially since my definition wouldn't make it a required variable.

Anyways, here's the output if you want **exactly** what you discussed, not nearly as pretty. I am not sure how to manually shade in those regions, but please share if you figure it out.

```
cluster_overload = pd.read_csv("TSplot.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
grouped = cluster_overload.groupby(['Cluster','Week'],as_index=False)
stats = grouped.agg(['min','mean','max']).unstack().T
stats.index = stats.index.droplevel(0)

colors = ['b','g','r']
ax = stats.loc['mean'].plot(color=colors, alpha=0.8, linewidth=3)
stats.loc['max'].plot(ax=ax,color=colors,legend=False, alpha=0.3)
stats.loc['min'].plot(ax=ax,color=colors,legend=False, alpha=0.3)
```

Outputs:[image]