# Seaborn lineplot with min & max as a shaded area

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a team's score in a competition over time, compared to the max and the min of teams' scores at that time. I have a [working example with min & max as lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX3vd.png).

However, I would prefer showing the min and the max via a shaded area, a bit like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Dhd.png) but without the average of the min and max being plotted (the blue line).

Can someone more competent in Seaborn or matplotlib help me out?

I've unsuccessfully tried:

- stopping the min & max's average line from being calculated at all
- hiding the min & max's average line (e.g. reducing its size to 0)
- tweaking Seaborn's confidence interval "ci" as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767719/timeseries-plot-with-min-max-shading-using-seaborn)

I have a preference for using Seaborn because of its nice "look & feel" but at this point, I'll take whatever works.

---

Dataset shown on the graph

```
      timestamp group    score
4  1.563890e+09    13    0.000
0  1.563890e+09   min    0.000
0  1.563890e+09   max  100.000
4  1.563890e+09    13    0.000
0  1.563890e+09   min    0.000
0  1.563890e+09   max   99.675
4  1.563890e+09    13    0.000
0  1.563890e+09   min    0.000
0  1.563890e+09   max   99.675
0  1.563890e+09    13   39.101
0  1.563890e+09   min    0.000
0  1.563890e+09   max   74.573
0  1.563890e+09    13   39.101
0  1.563890e+09   min   37.853
0  1.563890e+09   max   74.573`
```

---

code of first screenshot (scoreboard is a larger pandas dataframe)

```py
s = scoreboard[(scoreboard.group == 13) | (scoreboard.group == "max") | (scoreboard.group == "min")]
sns.lineplot(x="timestamp", y="score", hue="group", data=s, marker="o")
```

---

code of second screenshot (scoreboard is a larger pandas dataframe)

```py
s = scoreboard[(scoreboard.group == 13)]
s0 = scoreboard[(scoreboard.group == "max") | (scoreboard.group == "min")]

sns.lineplot(x="timestamp", y="score", data=s0, marker="o")
sns.lineplot(x="timestamp", y="score", data=s, marker="o")
```

---

Comment: You can achieve it via [fill_between()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html). It's hard to try with the example you give. Could you post some of your raw data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the data, it's not obvious how to give you specific lines of code.
But considering how you are thinking of it, which is overlaying a glyph over another, I recommend you look at Bokeh. It's another Python viz library, that provides exactly that and remains compatible with pandas dataset.

Comment: Thanks Erick, that was exactly what i was looking at when you posted your answer. I confirm Bokeh looks promising!