# Using group by in regression to define x and y values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

Is it possible to group the data (for defining x and y variables) for running regression directly in regPlot (or any other seaborn feature)? I am unable to find an inbuilt feature of that sort.

For example, in a column, I have a categorical variable "C", then I am trying to fit a regression line (with x and y) using the median for each category of C. Is there any functionality to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by your data with `pandas` first and then plot it with `seaborn`. Since you didn't provide your dataframe, I will use a seaborn sample dataset to demonstrate.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
# load dataframe
df = sns.load_dataset('car_crashes')
```

The dataframe looks like the following. `abbrev` column is a category column. I will use `total` and `speeding` variable as y and x.

[image]

First, use pandas `.groupby()` method and pass your categorical variable and in the meantime chain another method `.median()` so that pandas will aggregate your data and return the median for data. Pandas will return a dataframe that looks like the following
[image]

And then just call the column you want to plot. In our case, they are `total` and `speeding`. After, pass your x and y to seaborn `.regplot()`

```py
# group by
x = df.groupby(['abbrev']).median().speeding
y = df.groupby(['abbrev']).median().total
# plot
sns.regplot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: awesome.. works for me. A follow up question: the confidence interval showing now is created treating the x and y variables obtained after group by as inputs. Can we impose the confidence interval using the ungrouped data set (even though we are running regression using grouped one?)

Comment: For `seaborn` you can only change the size of the CI. If you need some equations for that please see [this web](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/regression-confidence-prediction-intervals) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164114/show-confidence-limits-and-prediction-limits-in-scatter-plot). If my answer is useful for your original question, please consider accepting it as the answer and vote up. Thanks.