# plotting confidence interval for linear regression line of a pandas time-series Dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, time-series, linear-regression

I have a sample time-series dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':'1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996',
                          '1997','1998','1999','2000'],
                   'count':[96,184,148,154,160,149,124,274,322,301,300]})
```

I want a `linear regression` line with `confidence interval` band in the `regression line`. Although I managed to plot a linear regression line. I am finding it difficult to plot the confidence interval band in the plot. Here is the snippet of my code for linear regression plot:

```
from matplotlib import ticker
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression



X = df.date_ordinal.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['count'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

reg = LinearRegression()

reg.fit(X, y)

predictions = reg.predict(X.reshape(-1, 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.scatter(X, y, color ='blue',alpha=0.5)

plt.plot(X, predictions,alpha=0.5, color = 'black',label = r'$N$'+ '= {:.2f}t + {:.2e}\n'.format(reg.coef_[0][0],reg.intercept_[0]))


plt.ylabel('count($N$)');
plt.xlabel(r'Year(t)');
plt.legend()


formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True) 
formatter.set_powerlimits((-1,1)) 
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)


plt.xticks(ticks = df.date_ordinal[::5], labels = df.index.year[::5])

           


plt.grid()  

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

This gives me a nice linear regression plot for time series .

**Problem & Desired output**
However, I need `confidence interval` for the `regression line` too as in:.[image]

Help on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116479/calculate-confidence-band-of-least-square-fit?

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164114/show-confidence-limits-and-prediction-limits-in-scatter-plot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that the package and function you use `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`  does not provide a way to simply obtain the confidence interval.

If you want to absolutely use `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`, you will have to dive into the methods of calculating a confidence interval. One popular approach is using bootstrapping, like was done with [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164114/show-confidence-limits-and-prediction-limits-in-scatter-plot).

However, the way I interpret your question, is that you are looking for a way to quickly do this inside of a plot command, similar to the screenshot you attached. If your goal is purely visualization, then you can simply use the `seaborn` package, which is also where your example image comes from.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lmplot(x='year', y='count', data=df, fit_reg=True, ci=95, n_boot=1000)
```

Where I have highlighted the three self-explanatory parameters of interest with their default values `fit_reg`, `ci`, and `n_boot`. Refer to [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) for a full description.

Under the hood, `seaborn` uses the `statsmodels` package. So if you want something in between purely visualization, and writing the confidence interval function from scratch yourself, I would refer you instead to using `statsmodels`. Specifically, look at [the documentation for calculating a confidence interval of an ordinary least squares (OLS) linear regression](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.conf_int.html).

The following code should give you a starting point for using statsmodels in your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000'],
                   'count':[96,184,148,154,160,149,124,274,322,301,300]})
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(float)
X = sm.add_constant(df['year'].values)
ols_model = sm.OLS(df['count'].values, X)
est = ols_model.fit()
out = est.conf_int(alpha=0.05, cols=None)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x='year',y='count',linestyle='None',marker='s', ax=ax)
y_pred = est.predict(X)
x_pred = df.year.values
ax.plot(x_pred,y_pred)

pred = est.get_prediction(X).summary_frame()
ax.plot(x_pred,pred['mean_ci_lower'],linestyle='--',color='blue')
ax.plot(x_pred,pred['mean_ci_upper'],linestyle='--',color='blue')

# Alternative way to plot
def line(x,b=0,m=1):
    return m*x+b

ax.plot(x_pred,line(x_pred,est.params[0],est.params[1]),color='blue')
```

[Which produces your desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdY3A.png)

While the values of everything are accessible via standard statsmodels functions.